# ÷ division sign in flutter dart

Tags: flutter, dart, icons, division

what is the name of division ÷ sign in icons section in flutter dart?

I tried this code but the sign is not ÷
FloatingActionButton(
onPressed: _divideCounter,
tooltip: 'divide',
backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
child: const Icon(Icons.gesture),
),

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
Icon(CupertinoIcons.divide)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want some special icons in your application. Just use these packages:

- font_awesome_flutter: https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter/install

```
icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.divide),
```

Here is the list of icons: [fontawesome](https://fontawesome.com/search)

- flutter_vector_icons: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_vector_icons/install

```
icon: AnimatedIcon(icon: AnimatedIcons.divide)
```

Here is the list of icons: [flutter-vector-icons](https://flutter-vector-icons.vercel.app/#/)

Install these packages by run command in your project directory:

```
flutter pub add <package_name>
```

Answer (score -1):

Flutter use Material Icons from material UI.

if you use VSCode , actually you can preview the icons.

or you can find all the icons on documentation of material UI here
https://mui.com/material-ui/material-icons/