# ÷ division sign Icon in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I need this `÷` sign in my app.

what is the name of the division `÷` sign in the icons section in Flutter Dart Material?

I tried this code but the sign does not exist.

```
IconButton(onPressed: _divideCounter, icon:Icon(Icons.division))
```

Comment: you can use https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter package, This package have variety of icons. For eg: `FontAwesomeIcons.divide`

Comment: Do you need it as an icon specifically? You can always just use that character as normal text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [÷ division sign in flutter dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73210553/%c3%b7-division-sign-in-flutter-dart)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a third-party package you can do this:

```dart
IconButton(
  onPressed: _divideCounter,
  icon: Text('÷', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0))
)
```

Adjust the font size as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want some special icons in your application. Just use these packages:

- font_awesome_flutter: https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter/install

```
icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.divide),
```

Here is the list of icons: [fontawesome](https://fontawesome.com/search)

- flutter_vector_icons: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_vector_icons/install

```
icon: AnimatedIcon(icon: AnimatedIcons.divide)
```

Here is the list of icons: [flutter-vector-icons](https://flutter-vector-icons.vercel.app/#/)

Install these packages by run command in your project directory:

```
flutter pub add <package_name>
```